# PHP echo custom fields with $out

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, advanced-custom-fields

i am using the Favorites plugin in Wordpress to save posts. I'm trying to adjust the way the information is displayed though. All the styling etc works below and my divs are being included, however i am struggling to pull information through to fill the divs. Fore example, i am trying to pull the excerpt in to the p.details but it is just throwing out an empty result, with no errors. Similarly, i am trying to pull through an acf custom field of 'bath' into p.bath but that is also empty. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
if ( is_multisite() ) switch_to_blog($this->site_id);

    $out = '<ul class="property-list" data-userid="' . $this->user_id . '" data-links="true" data-siteid="' . $this->site_id . '" ';
    $out .= ( $include_button ) ? 'data-includebuttons="true"' : 'data-includebuttons="false"';
    $out .= ( $this->links ) ? ' data-includelinks="true"' : ' data-includelinks="false"';
    $out .= ' data-nofavoritestext="' . $no_favorites . '"';
    $out .= ' data-posttype="' . $post_types . '"';
    $out .= '>';
    foreach ( $favorites as $key => $favorite ){
        $out .= '<li data-postid="' . $favorite . '">';
        $out .= '<div class="third-1">';
        $out .= '<a class="property-thumb" href="' . get_permalink($favorite) . '">';
        $out .= '</a>';
        $out .= '</div>';
        $out .= '<div class="third-2">';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '<h3 class="name"><a href="' . get_permalink($favorite) . '">';
        $out .= get_the_title($favorite);
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '</a></h3>';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '<h4 class="price">';
        $out .= '£' . '300';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '</h4>';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '<p class="details">';
        $out .= the_excerpt();
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '</p>';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '<p class="bed">';
        $out .= '1';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '</p>';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '<p class="bath">';
        $out .= '1';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '</p>';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '<a class="full-details" href="' . get_permalink($favorite) . '">';
        $out .= 'Full details';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '</a>';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '<a class="book-viewing" href="' . get_permalink($favorite) . '">';
        $out .= 'Book Viewing';
        if ( $this->links ) $out .= '</a>';
        $out .= '</div>';
        $out .= '</li>';
    }
```

Comment: Is there actually anything in `the_excerpt()`?

Comment: The code u show here seems not the problem, look hee: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt  how to use **the_excerpt**

Comment: Hi, yeah there is content in the post which is pulling into other places throughout the site but just not in this plugin.

Comment: Thanks, although the_excerpt(); has served me well to date. How do you think i'm using it wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `the_excerpt();` to `get_the_excerpt();` and it *should* work.

Comment: That doesnt work either unfortunately. Do you think i need to start a wp_query before of something?

Comment: Possibly. It's hard to pinpoint what's going wrong without knowing where/how this code is placed in your theme.